# Factorial function producing wrong results

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

I know that there are more than one way of calculating the factorial of an integer as well as there is a `math` module. However I tried to put together a simple function that is returning a wrong result. I would love to know what went wrong here. Such as if I pass 2 as parameter it returns 3, if 3 it returns 8.

```
>>>def factorial(n):

        if n > 0:
            result = n * n-1
            factorial(n-1)
            return result 

>>>factorial (2)

   3
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What if n is equal to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your function:

- You don't return anything if the condition `n > 0` is false.
- `n * n-1` calculates `(n * n) - 1`, you probably intended `n * (n - 1)`
- You call `factorial` recursively, but then don't do anything with the result. Currently your code acts just like if you had only written `return n * n - 1` inside the if.

Answer (score 8):

You're missing a couple different things here. First off, you need to actually multiply by the result of the recursive call, otherwise that recursion isn't doing anything for you. Secondly, you need to specify a base case for the recursion to end. That is, you need to tell the function what to do when n == 0. You're looking for something like:

```
if n == 0:
    return 1
elif n > 0:
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

My python is rusty so that syntax could be off, but you get the idea.

Also, note that the reason for the returns you are getting is that your function is essentially calculating `n*n-1`, which due to order of operations gives you one less than the square of `n`.

One more thing, just for fun. The function as I've written it so far will create a large stack for big numbers, which may or may not be a good idea. So an alternative is to make it tail-recursive. Many compilers will optimize tail-recursive functions, though according to the comments Python does not. To do this you want to implement an accumulator, like so:

```
def factorial(acc, n):
    if n == 0:
        return acc
    elif n > 0:
        return factorial(n*acc, n-1)
```

You will then call the function with `factorial(1,n)`, or you can also write this as a helper function that handles that part for you.

Comment: No need for the else. And it's `elif` in Python anyways.

Comment: I just didn't want your post to get attacked by others :). So +1 for you.

Comment: @JohnY Ah geez. Here I go correcting people and I don't even remember correctly.  Thanks.  Too much Perl.

Comment: Python does not optimize tail recursion.

Comment: +1 Also, lambda: `f = lambda x: x*f(x-1) if x > 0 else 1` (completely irrelevant, but I thought someone should mention it)

Answer (score 1):

You just need this, I think simplest form:

```
 def factorial(n):
     if n == 0: return 1
     return n * factorial(n-1)
```

some runs:

```
>>> factorial(1)
1
>>> factorial(13)
6227020800
```

You can also use this form:

```
def factorial(n): 
    if(n): return n*factorial(n-1)
    return 1
```

its kind of addition with @sepp2k 's answer